# Cross platform class library for Mac and Windows using C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, portable-class-library, .net-standard

I'm about creating an application which should run on Mac as well on Windows and should be deployed to the respective stores. The GUI will be a HTML-based GUI hosted locally in a WebView control. The GUI will mainly communicate with the rest of the system using simple Json messages.

The main logic is the same for both platforms and I would like to share as much code as possible. The idea is to use Xamarin on Mac and .NET on Windows and build a common class library which can be shared.

What should be the target of this shared assembly (PCL, netstandard or have different project files for Mac and Windows and just share the source files?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use .NET standard for all new projects, because it will replace PCLs in long term.
See paragraph `As a library author, what should I do now?` on
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/

> As a library author, you should consider switching to .NET Standard because it will replace Portable Class Libraries for targeting multiple .NET platforms.
>
> In case of .NET Standard 1.x the set of available APIs is very similar to PCLs. But .NET Standard 2.x will have a significantly bigger API set and will also allow you to depend on libraries targeting .NET Framework.
>
> The key differences between PCLs and .NET Standard are:
>
> - Platform tie-in.
> - Platform availability.
> - Library availability.

I'd use a shared library (code file sharing) only if I have to have small pieces that are platform specific. But usually you should just create an interface and implement the platform specifics in classes that are implementing the interface. And then use dependency injection to get the actual implementation in your cross platform library.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use [PCL](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/). I have apps for Windows 10(Net Core), for Android and iOS(Xamarin Forms).  These apps use the PCL library. It is the best way.

Comment: Can you justify why PCL is the best way?